# High PREEMPTIVE_OS Wait Stats

Tags: sql-server-2016, wait-types

How to reduce PREEMPTIVE_OS_AUTHENTICATIONOPS wait type stats in SQL Server, any advice on it would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`PREEMPTIVE_OS_AUTHENTICATIONOPS` is how SQL Server reports the time taken while waiting for the operating system to authenticate users.

Optimizing those waits would consist of reducing the number of times SQL Server needs to authenticate a user, and speeding up the response times for Windows Authentication such as ensuring your Domain Controllers aren't over capacity.

SQLSkills.com has some quite detailed info about `PREEMPTIVE_OS_AUTHENTICATIONOPS` at their [site](https://www.sqlskills.com/help/waits/preemptive_os_authenticationops/).